# is this a good practice for a database for products with multiple units,cost price & expiry dates

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I a working on a database that is going to have a product with multiple expiration date, multiple cost prices and therefore there will multiple stock entries for the same product, I have made an initial database design for this and I wanted to ask you guys if this is a good practice or not. If not please advise me on how to do it the right way.

This is what I have thought about so far.

Creating 3 tables (1. Product_info - 2.Product_Stock - 3.units)
and below is the detailed structure:

```
    Units Table
--------------------------
id Name 
  |------|
1 |Piece |
2 |Pack  |
3 |Kilos |
```

Here I will list all the units that I will use as the base product unit.

```
                Product Information Table
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
id Name   AvgCostPrice AvgPrice AvgPackCostPrice AvgPackPrice totalQuantity BaseUnitID  multiplier PackBarcode  Barcode
  |------|------------|--------|----------------|------------|-------------|----------|----------|------------|--------|
1 |Soda  |            |        |                |            |  108        | 1        | 12       |   111111   | 111222 |
2 |Water |            |        |                |            |  50         | 1        | 6        |   222222   | 222111 |
```

1. in the above table the average cost price and selling price for the packs and piece will be calculated from the different stocks I have for the said product.
2. The multiplier column will be for how much pieces does a product pack hold.
3. The Total Quantity will hold the sum of different stock quantities I have in the (Product Stock Table) ,Also it will only sum the quantity for base unit of the product. 
   for example: if the base unit of soda is pack, then it will sum the (PackQTY) Column in (Product Stock Table). and if else it will sum  (Quantity) in that table.

```
                Product Stock Table
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id ProdID UnitID  CustomBarcode  Quantity      PackQTY  CostPrice Price   PackCostPrice  PackPrice expDate        Enabled
  |------|-------|--------------|-------------|-------|----------|-------|--------------|---------|--------------|---------
1 |1     |   1   |              |     84      | 7     | 2.0      | 2.4   | 24.0         | 29      |  20/may/2019 |  1
2 |1     |   1   |              |     24      | 2     | 1.5      | 1.9   | 18.0         | 23      |  10/aug/2019 |  1
2 |2     |   3   |              |     50      | 0     | 3.0      | 5.0   | 0.0          | 0       |  10/Feb/2019 |  1
```

1.The enabled column will work as a (Boolean) to determine whether to use this stock while selling. 
for example: if I wanted to sell a soda Can and I have two Stocks for it. if stock number one is 0 then enable column will be false and therefore it will only subtract the quantity sold from stock number two and use its price and cost price in the (SalesDetails Table)

2. Custom Barcode Column will be used to separate stocks when having a discount on almost expired stock.

And I also thought of separating the different units for each product stock in (Stock Table)

So, when I want to sell 24 pieces of soda and 3 packs of soda it will choose the oldest stock depending on its (Enabled Column Value = True)and subtract that quantity from it and if it reaches zero then (Enabled column) Value will change to false.

after that it will go again and do the same but this time it will change the value of PackQtY from 7 to 4 and the Quantity Column Value will be calculated through this [ Product_Stock.Quantity= Product_Stock.Quantity - (QtySold * Prodcut_info.Multiplier Column Value) ] which will be      84-(3*12)= 48

And the sales details structure output will be like this:

```
                Sale Details Table
----------------------------------------------------------
id ProdID UnitID    Quantity   CostPrice    Price   total  CostTotal
  |------|-------|-----------|-------------|-------|------|---------| 
1 |1     |   1   |    24     |     2.0     | 2.4   | 57.6 | 48.0    |
2 |1     |   2   |    3      |     18.0    | 23.0  | 69.0 | 54.0    |
```

```
                Product Stock Table (After Selling 24 pieces of Soda and 3 packs of Soda)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id ProdID UnitID  CustomBarcode  Quantity      PackQTY  CostPrice Price   PackCostPrice  PackPrice expDate        Enabled
  |------|-------|--------------|-------------|-------|----------|-------|--------------|---------|--------------|---------
1 |1     |   1   |              |     48      | 4     | 2.0      | 2.4   | 24.0         | 29      |  20/may/2019 |  1
2 |1     |   1   |              |     0       | 0     | 1.5      | 1.9   | 18.0         | 23      |  10/aug/2019 |  0
```

Sorry if I didn't explain it very well.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Off-topic for many reasons. Unfortunately no one can offer effective feedback without extensive and intimate knowledge of the system you model. Nor do you provide actual DDL, making evaluation of your model very difficult. If you are concerned, you should hire someone with the appropriate expertise. It might be helpful to review the sample databases created by Microsoft.

Comment: Have you done ER (entity-relationship diagram)? If so, could you add image of it?

Comment: @SMor Thank you very much for your reply. but at the moment I am still at the very first stage. thinking about how the system would work before writhing core code.

Comment: @VanNg if you are asking about something like this [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/images/entityrelation2.png)

then I will try post it later as I am at work now. and btw I am still learning both SQL (Still have some confusion about one to many and many to many relationships) and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to be careful about how you use nouns.
For example: "Price" does not mean the same as "Cost" and "CostPrice" sounds like an oxymoron. I suggest that you restrict your yourself to using either Cost or Price.

Van Ng asks if you have done an Entity Relationship diagram. Well, at the stage that you seem to be at, it is probably unwise to start with an ER diagram because an ER diagram is helpful as a summary of a model that you have already defined - and you are not yet at that stage.

Averages: If you design your database schema correctly then you can calculate data such as averages. You don't need averages as base tables.

I recommend that you consider using the fact-based modeling method called "[object-role modeling](http://www.ormfoundation.org/)"(ORM)  because you can start with "the facts" before thinking about drawing ER diagrams.

**Example:** 
I used the NORMA ORM tool to create the following example:

First, I read your text, extracted facts and then used the facts to design an object-role model.
Then I used the NORMA tool to generate a "logical view" of the object-role model. (happens in milliseconds)

I did not add everything that you mention but I hope that this will be enough to help you to make progress.

The example contains two artefacts:

1: The logical model that was ***generated*** by the NORMA tool.

2: The facts from which the logical model was generated.

[[image: The automatically generated logical model[2]]

[image: The facts from which the logical model was generated]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

So, I guess I have something new to learn before starting anything on this project.

I believe this is just an example as you did not include all the information I have.
Also you are right about the stage where I am at at the moment. Still planning every thing on paper and figuring out problems that I will face and the solutions for them.

Comment: my main problem in short is that I have a product that has 3 main things to deal with : 
Multiple Expiry Dates for the same product. 
Selling the same product in pieces and packs (selling with one unit will affect the other)
Different costs for the same product.

Comment: In most tasks, including data modeling, people start by speaking or writing sentences that refer to states of affairs. What you do with ORM is to (1) study ambiguous sentences in natural language (2) Extract formal sentences and draw ORM diagrams (3) use the NORMA tool to generate a formal verbalisation of the ORM diagrams.   ORM helps you to think clearly about your problem and the NORMA tool guides you to express your thoughts in a formal language.